# bash read line exits 1

Tags: bash, readline, exit-code

I want to read each lines from an input. Each line is successfully read in a while loop. However the loop ends with the status 1:

```
$ incr=0
$ while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]] ; do    
  incr=$((incr+1));    
  echo "$incr: $line"; 
done < <(echo -e "one \ntwo\tthree\nfour")
1: one 
2: two  three
3: four

$ echo "status ${PIPESTATUS[@]}" 
status 1
```

Why do I get an exit status different than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 appears to be the exit status of the command (`[[ -n "$line" ]]`) that caused the `while` loop to exit in the first place. It's possible this is a bug in `bash`, or at least an undocumented difference in which command(s) set `$?` vs `PIPESTATUS`.

You can observe the same difference in a much simpler command:

```
$ while false; do echo foo; done
$ printf '%s\n' "$?" "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0
1
```

Comment: Do you mean that a while loop always exits with a status different than 0? I just noticed that. Unless you enter it at least once and exit with a break.

Comment: From the man page: "The exit
              status of the while and until commands is the exit status of the last do list command executed, or  zero
              if none was executed." (`list` here is the body of the loop). `PIPESTATUS` appears to pick up the exit status of the *condition* instead, and it isn't clear to me if that is a bug or an undocumented expectation.